# Let $I=[0,1]$ and $T:L^{1}(I)\rightarrow L^{1}(I)$ defined by $T(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$. Then $T$ is injective.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $I=[0,1]$ and $T:L^{1}(I)\rightarrow L^{1}(I)$ defined by
$$T(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt, \quad f\in L^{1}(I),\: x\in I.$$

Show that $T$ is inyective.

**Remark:** If $f$ were a continuous function, then by the fundamental theorem of calculus we have that if $T(f)=0$, then $f=0$.

The **problem** is when $f$ is not continuous, in this case, I think that we can not show $f=0$, the most we can pretend is $f=0$ almost surely, but I have not been able to show it.

---

**Added:**

I want to share the following reasoning and know if it is correct, I appreciate the answers you have given so far.

Let $f\in L^{1}(I)$ suc that $Tf=0$, then for al $x\in I$ we have $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=0$, then

> **Fact 1:** For all interval $J\subset I$ we have $\int_{J}f(t)dt=0$.
>
> *Proof:* Let $a,b \in I$ the extreme points of $J$ with $a<b$, then 
>   $$\int_{J}f(t)dt=\int_{a}^{b}f(t)dt=\int_{0}^{b}f(t)dt-\int_{0}^{a}f(t)dt=Tf(b)-Tf(a)=0.$$

But we know that

> **Theorem 1:** Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function, then $f$ is Riemann integrable if and only if $\lambda\left(\left\{x\in[a,b]\: : \: f \mbox{ is discontinuous in }x\right\}\right)=0$ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue measure in $I$.

Since $f\in L^{1}(I)$ then $f$ is Riemann integrable in $I$, furthermore, $f$ is Riemann integrable in $J$ for all $J\subseteq I$. Also by the definition of integral of Riemann we must have $f$ bounded in $I$. Therefore, $f$ is continuous  $\lambda$ almost everywhere in $I$.

Let $x\in I$ such that $f$ is contiuous in $x$, then there exists an inteval $J\subset I$ with $x\in J$ such that $f $ is continuous in $J$, we consider $a,b\in I$ the extreme points of $J$ with $a<b$, then we consider
$F:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(y)=\int_{a}^{y}f(t)dt$ for all $y\in J$, since $f$ is continuous in $J$, then $F'(y)=f(y)$.

Thus, for each $y\in J$ we conisder the  interval $J_{y}\subset J$ with extreme points $a$ and $y$, then   by **Fact 1** we have
$$0=\int_{J_{y}}f(t)dt=\int_{a}^{y}f(t)dt=F(y).$$
Then $F(y)=0$ for all $y\in J$, then $f(y)=F'(y)=0$ for all $y\in J$, in particular, $f(x)=0$.

Therefore, $f=0$  $\lambda$ almost everywhere in $I$.

Comment: It might be important here that you're working over $L^1(I)\cong\mathcal{L}^1(I)/N$, where $N = \{f\in\mathcal{L}^1(I)\mid ||f||_1 = 0\}$

Comment: The function $Tf$ is absolutely continuous. So the derivative of $Tf$ exists a.e. and equals $f$ a.e.. That's enough to show that if $Tf=0$, then $f=0$ in $L^1$.

Comment: @Mark   I have posted an attempt, I would like to know your opinion.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts I have posted an attempt, I would like to know your opinion.

Comment: I guess you are considering $L^1$ to consist of Riemann integrable functions. Your argument works for that case. The same holds for Lebesgue integrable functions, too, by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem: If $f \in L^1(I)$ is Lebesgue integrable on $I=[a,b]$, then $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ is differentiable a.e., with $F'(x)=f(x)$ a.e.. This theorem is usually proved in the context of absolutely continuous functions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Suppose $T(f)=0$. Let $A=\{x\mid f(x)>\frac{1}{n}\}$. Show that $\int_A f\,\textrm{d}\mu=0$, so $\mu(A)=0$.

Comment: I have posted an attempt, I would like to know your opinion.

Comment: @DiegoFonseca: It doesn't quite work. An integrable function need not be Riemann integrable. Maybe you can show that every function in $L^1$ is equal to a Riemann integrable function almost everywhere, but it does not seem obvious. Instead, just consider the family of all measurable sets over which the integral of $f$ is zero and show that it is a $\sigma$-algebra.